# C# - Json POST request sent but not received by PHP server

Tags: c#, php, json, post, request

I am sending a HTTP request from a C# windowsform application to PHP server hosted on OpenShift (Redhat). I am using the method POST, with Json data.

The problem is that :

- the data seemed to be correctly sent (I see the packets in wireshark)
- the php script is correctly launch and I see in the log that a POST message is received
- but no POST data are beeing received ..

**Here is the C# code** :

```
string json = "{\"user\":\"test\"," +
                "\"n\":\"2\"}";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://........rhcloud.com/webservices.php");

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.ContentLength = json.Length;

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    streamWriter.Write(json);
    streamWriter.Close();

    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
         var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
         Debug.WriteLine("R : " + result);
    }
}
```

**Here is the PHP code** :

```
echo "Start Saving ! ";

// Handle Posted Data From C# App
if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST))
{
    echo 'Data Recieved';
}
else
{
  // Error
  echo 'No POST Data Found';
}
```

**The function always return** : "Start Saving ! No POST Data Found".

**Here is the log line on the server** : 
[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14737942/log.png]

**Here is the line in wireshark** : 
[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14737942/Wireshark_capture.png]

Is someone seeing the problem? Do not hesitate to tell me if I am not clear.
Could it be Openshift which intercept the data ? Does my php file have a problem?

Comment: You should make sure you post to exact same domain. I mean that you for example might post data to `example.com` and `example.com` makes redirection to `www.example.com` and then it won't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP's `$_POST` does not understand JSON.

What you want is something along the lines of

```
// Error handling is left as an exercise
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

You should then be able to use `$input` the way you seem to want to use `$_POST`. See [`json_decode`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) for additional knobs to twiddle.

Comment: Thank you very much !
It totally fixed my problem :)

Comment: This save my life. In Android a simple $_Post will do, but in c# this line of code is the coolest line of code.