# C# WebClient upload string not working correctly

Tags: c#, php, json

So I'm trying to set POST data of a remote PHP script. This script uses the POST data as filename and retrieves a JSON file with it. But this sadly does not work. It retrieves the data with no values. Here is how it works:

C#:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    byte[] saveData = client.UploadData(
       "http://" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["scripturi"].ToString() + "storeData.php",
        "POST",
        System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("filename="+ dt.bedrijfsNaam));
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$host='myip';
$user='username';
$pass='userpass';
$db='mydatabase';

$link= mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db) or die(msqli_error($link));

$filename = $_POST['filename'] . '.json';

$json = file_get_contents(__DIR__."/json/".$filename);// my thoughts are that something is wrong in this line?
$obj = json_decode($json);

$query_opslaan = "INSERT INTO skMain (BedrijfsName, ContPers, TelNum, email, Land, Plaats, PostCode) VALUES ('". $obj->bedrijfsNaam ."' , '". $obj->ContPers ."', '". $obj->TelNum ."', '". $obj->email ."', '". $obj->Land ."', '". $obj->Plaats ."', '". $obj->PostCode ."')";

mysqli_query($link, $query_opslaan) or die(mysqli_error($query_opslaan));
?>
```

it should retrieve correct data from the JSON file but instead it retrieves no values it all and the query stores blank data into the database. I think I used the C# script wrong and that's why I also think that the $json variable is not working correctly. But I don't exactly know what I did wrong. Can someone please help me?

Comment: what is value of `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["scripturi"].ToString()`

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/25005434/5001784

Comment: But I already have something like that answer as you can see in my PHP code

Comment: show me `true` flag in `$json = file_get_contents(__DIR__."/json/".$filename);`

Comment: I don't use it as an array, I use it as an object instead. The result will be the same as an array

Answer (score 1):

When you lookup the doc for the PHP [`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) you'll find:

> An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method when using application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data as the HTTP Content-Type in the request.

This means the content you [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)) to the server has to be one of those Content-Types and its body need to match the expected format.

In your code you use the  `UploadData` method. That method doesn't do any magic for you. It simply POSTs the bytes you give it. Your request will look like this on the wire:

> ```
> POST /questions/ask HTTP/1.1
> Host: stackoverflow.com
> Content-Length: 13
> Expect: 100-continue
> Connection: Keep-Alive
>
> filename=test
> ```

You see that there is no Content-Type header.

There is however an other method called [`UploadValues`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w7b4fz7(v=vs.110).aspx) which takes an `NameValueCollection` and transforms its content to the needed x-www-form-urlencoded format for you:

```
using(var wc= new WebClient())
{
       var nv = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
       nv.Add("filename", "test");
       nv.Add("user", "bar");
       wc.UploadValues("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask", nv);
}
```

When executed the following is send to the server:

> ```
> POST /questions/ask HTTP/1.1
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> Host: stackoverflow.com
> Content-Length: 22
> Expect: 100-continue
>
> filename=test&user=bar
> ```

This last body content will lead to a populated `$_POST` array with *filename* and *user*.

When debugging these kind of requests make sure you run [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) so you can inspect the HTTP traffic.